# Restringir acesso a somente uma página na aplicação, deixando as demais livres

Tags: c#, asp.net, autenticação, web.config

Gostaria de restringir acesso solicitando login a apenas uma página na minha aplicação. No webconfig coloquei assim, mas obviamente dessa forma requer autenticação em todas as páginas da aplicação.

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">          
    </forms>
   </authentication>   
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
```

Eu poderia liberar as paginas fazendo assim, uma por uma:

```
 <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
       <authorization>
          <allow users="?"/>  
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>
```

Porém, gostaria de deixar livre todas as paginas, exceto uma na pasta ~/Admin/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mesclar os dois códigos da pergunta e modificar um pouco, da seguinte forma:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">          
    </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
     <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<location path="foo.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>  
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Assim você libera o site inteiro pra todo mundo, mas também nega apenas uma página específica para os não autenticados. Na página "foo.aspx" da configuração acima a regra de negar se sobrepõe à de liberar, por ser mais específica - porém note que ela nega acesso apenas aos não autenticados.

Comment: não resolveu assim. Quero solicitar login apenas se o usuário tentar acessar um recurso, no caso uma página específica; As demais deixo livre.

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi o meu problema usando o `ActionFilterAttribute`

Basta criar o filtro como o da primeira imagem, usando a logica que você necessita.

E basta adicionar o filter no Controller desejado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]